# Getting all items for selected period using Leaflet.TimeDimension?

Tags: leaflet, timeslider

I use the leaflet plugin: leaflet.TimeDimension

Is it possible, when choosing a period of one year, to receive all elements associated with this year when displayed? Currently, when selecting a 1 year period, not all records related to that year are displayed.

```
this.map.options['timeDimensionOptions'] =
     {
         timeInterval: "1989/1991",
         period: "P1Y"
     };

 let tdWmsLayer = (L as any).timeDimension.layer.wms(this.selectedLayer.mapLayer.layer, {
      requestTimeFromCapabilities: true,
      //updateTimeDimension: true,
      setDefaultTime: true
    });
```

in the request, the times parameter is sent completely, when in theory you can only send a year. Or am I doing something wrong?

URL: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TIS_DEVELOP/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=geo_shp_wells_test&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&cql_filter=1%3D1&time=1990-12-31T19%3A00%3A00.000Z&width=256&height=256&crs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=6261721.357121639,7514065.628545967,7514065.628545968,8766409.899970293`

parameters:`service: WMS
request: GetMap
layers: geo_shp_wells_test
styles: 
format: image/png
transparent: true
version: 1.3.0
cql_filter: 1=1
time: 1990-12-31T19:00:00.000Z
width: 256
height: 256
crs: EPSG:3857
bbox: 6261721.357121639,7514065.628545967,7514065.628545968,8766409.899970293`

Comment: please add the actual URL of the call being made

Comment: @IanTurton added

Comment: I know that "time" must be "1990" in order to receive items in a year, but I cannot understand how to make such "time" through this plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify this line in the [source file](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/blob/8045c2e8a62520fe647e41ab5801fe6bc7b021af/dist/leaflet.timedimension.src.js#L939) from

```js
wmsParams.time = new Date(time).toISOString();
```

to

```js
wmsParams.time = new Date(time).getFullYear();
```

Here is a demonstration: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/j5s3cL6v/).

Comment: @TomazicM I asked the question on the example of the year, and if for example a period of a month would have to be? Simply it would be desirable, that "time" in request was not filled with not set part. For example: period: P1Y query: time: 1990 or period: P1M (month) time: 1990-02

Comment: I think you can figure that out on your own. ;-) You could play around with the available [methods of the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#JavaScript_Date_instances), or simply split the date string by the first or second hyphen, depending on requirement.

Answer (score 2):

@Stefan's answer is essentially right, but more correct way of modifying TimeDimension plugin would be through extending/modifying it with `include` method, thus without need to edit source:

```
L.TimeDimension.Layer.WMS.include({
  _createLayerForTime: function(time){
      wmsParams.time = new Date(time).getFullYear();
      return new this._baseLayer.constructor(this._baseLayer.getURL(), wmsParams);
  }
});
```